# ruby - heroku: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, heroku, rbenv

this question has been posted befour, but the answers haven't worked. I should proberley mention that i am completely new to ruby.  i incountered the error while doing a tutorial
 here are the steps:

`[first_app (master)]$ gem install heroku`

I get

```
Successfully installed heroku-2.24.0
```

but when i try

`[first_app (master)]$ heroku keys:add`

I get

```
-bash: heroku: command not found
```

i then tried a bunch uninstalling the gem updating bundle reinstalling it but that hasn't helped

```
$ bundle exec heroku
```

`/Users/vng/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in` `` `block in replace_gem': heroku is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/vng/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/heroku:18:in ``'`

```
echo $PATH
```

`/Users/vng/.rbenv/shims:/Users/vng/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

my gem environment

> RubyGems Environment:
>     - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
>     - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
>     - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/vng/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
>     - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/vng/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
>     - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/vng/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin
>     - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>       - ruby
>       - x86_64-darwin-11
>     - GEM PATHS:
>        - /Users/vng/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
>        - /Users/vng/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
>     - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>        - :update_sources => true
>        - :verbose => true
>        - :benchmark => false
>        - :backtrace => false
>        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>     - REMOTE SOURCES:
>        - http://rubygems.org/

help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have you tried the recommended approach of installing the Heroku Toolbelt - https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/  If you do, I'd uninstall that gem (which has always worked for me as well).

Answer (score 9):

When you install gems that have binaries (executables) you must run

```
rbenv rehash
```

to add the executables to your path.