# The heroku command exists in these Ruby versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

After I updated my Ruby version with rbenv I wasn't able to use the Heroku command-line tool.
I got this error:

```
> heroku
rbenv: heroku: command not found

The `heroku' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.0.0-p195
```

Reinstalling the tool belt from [toolbelt.heroku.com](https://toolbelt.heroku.com) didn't help.

Comment: What about the solution to accept of an answer of any? =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The \`heroku' command exists in these Ruby versions:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093044/the-heroku-command-exists-in-these-ruby-versions)

Comment: I wonder how a duplicate can be almost two 2 years older than the original ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I switched to my previous Ruby version 2.0.0p195 and uninstalled the gem 'heroku'

```
rbenv global 2.0.0p195

gem uninstall heroku
```

Then I switched to the latest Ruby version 2.0.0p353 and reinstalled Toolbelt [toolbelt.heroku.com](https://toolbelt.heroku.com)

```
rbenv global 2.0.0p353
```

Comment: This.  Holy balls I was getting so frustrated by this issue.  Thank you!

Comment: After removing the heroku gem from all other versions of Ruby that rbenv had and switching back to the latest desired version using

rbenv global 2.3.0

I needed to run

rbenv rehash

to get the toolbelt heroku command to be found.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using `rbenv`, here are the steps I follow to fix this.

**The error**

```
rbenv: heroku: command not found

The `heroku' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.2.2
```

**What to do**

1. `rbenv local 2.2.2`
2. `gem uninstall heroku`
3. `rbenv rehash`

Good to go!

Comment: why would you need to switch to a specific version? why can't you make the executable run on your current version?

Answer (score 4):

Heroku does not recommend using `heroku` gem from the recent times. If you have already installed the gem, uninstall the gem first with:

```
$ gem uninstall heroku
```

then install the toolbelt from Heroku as [specified on Heroku site](https://toolbelt.heroku.com):

For [ubuntu/debian](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/debian):

```
$ wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

For [other linux](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone):

```
$ wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

For [Windows](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows)/[MacOS](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/osx) see instructions on links.

Comment: It was need to close it under condition if installed.

Comment: To uninstall the old versions of `heroku` you'll need to switch to the Ruby version that it's installed for, uninstall the gem, reinstall the Toolbelt and then change the global Ruby version back to the newer one.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. I had the heroku gem install on various ruby versions and despite the fact I had installed the heroku toolbelt from that package downloaded from their site, I was still getting:

```
rbenv: heroku: command not found
```

I found that after I had uninstalled the gem from all my ruby versions I had to run:

```
rbenv rehash
```

After that I found that everything work perfectly. I found this out from this stackoverflow answer:

[ruby - heroku: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062074/ruby-heroku-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, if you do the following command in the terminal:

```
which convert
```

And you get back this: Users/user_name/.rbenv/shims/convert, you should remove this file in your shims.

```
rm Users/user_name/.rbenv/shims/convert
```

If you do which convert again it should give back a different url: /usr/local/bin/convert

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, the thing here is that `rbenv` was getting confused along with `brew` and the `heroku` binary.

Heroku recommends a `brew` install for Macs. Now, you need to make sure that you don't have the gem installed with any other `Ruby` version managed with `rbenv`.

If you do, just reinstall them, and you'll be good to go.