# $PATH issues with RVM and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm, gemset

having an annoying problem here. my $PATH is as follows:

```
/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:

/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:

/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:

/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:

/usr/sbin:/sbin:

/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:

/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/bin:
```

running `which ruby` gives me this:

```
/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
```

I get the error `no such file or directory` when I run $PATH.

```
rvm list
```

turns no error out

I also can't run `rails -v`, as it gives me the error:

```
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
```

Not sure what to try, any help is greatly appreciated

## EDIT

I think my system is running rails version 0.9.5 for some strange reason.

```
/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-0.9.5/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've been using rails 4.0.2, not sure whats going on here...

## EDIT

```
-bash: cd: /Users/sherwyn/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin: No such file or directory
```

I uninstalled the old version of rails

```
gem uninstall rails '0.9.5'
```

which allowed me to do `rails -v` and work with 4.0.2.

When I say "run $PATH" I mean I type "$PATH" into the console.

## Edit

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/Rakefile:require 'rake/rdoctask'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/formatador-0.2.4/Rakefile:require 'rake/rdoctask'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.2.4/Rakefile:require 'rake/rdoctask'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/doc/release_notes/rake-10.0.0.rdoc:* The deprecated <tt>rake/rdoctask.rb</tt> library has been removed.
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/doc/release_notes/rake-10.0.1.rdoc:* The deprecated <tt>rake/rdoctask.rb</tt> library has been removed.
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/doc/release_notes/rake-10.0.2.rdoc:* The deprecated <tt>rake/rdoctask.rb</tt> library has been removed.
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/doc/release_notes/rake-10.0.3.rdoc:* The deprecated <tt>rake/rdoctask.rb</tt> library has been removed.
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:fail "ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. " +
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/Rakefile:    'lib/rake/rdoctask.rb',
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rdoc-4.1.1/History.rdoc:  * Added rdoc/task.rb containing a replacement for rake/rdoctask.rb.  Use
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.38/Rakefile:require 'rake/rdoctask'
```

Comment: What do you mean "run $PATH", `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Start over, it's easy enough to do.

Comment: start over with what? I havent changed anything about the path, the problem is that the folder in the first line of my path does not exist

Comment: `$PATH` is an environment variable, getting an error about not being able to find `$PATH` in the path is expected if you just type it (aka try to run it), instead `echo "$PATH"` to show what it is.

Comment: You have an extra "/Users/sherwyn" in "cd: /Users/sherwyn/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin"

Comment: I'm not even clear on what your question is at this point

Comment: enter into rails project folder and issue `grep rdoctask * -r`. And which is status of the issue?

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ output as follows above

Comment: I'm currently ignoring the problem and running server via bundle exec

Comment: Pay attention to 4 gems that use the rdoctask, probably they require the update.

Comment: have you use rvm/rbenv?

Comment: generally, you should not use the `vendor/bundle/` folder for open-source or easy-to-install gems. Use rvm/rbenv environments to keep gem set up-to-date, and away from the project.

Comment: I'm using RVM, but am not sure why it seems to be using the rails gem from /usr/bin/rails instead of from the rvm ruby version :(

Comment: because it is useful thing to split the areas for various project, you will avoid encountering the similar problems you have, to approximate to real work env or other servers.

Comment: I you can see you anyway use `bundle exec`, I believe, it get the gems from another repo. try `bundle show formatador`

Comment: /Users/sherwyn/Work/vvork/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/formatador-0.2.4

Comment: seems the same as above, you have to find out the defference, exec: `bundle show rails`?

Comment: /Users/sherwyn/Work/vvork/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.2

Comment: exactly that is, with `bundle exec` you have used non-system ruby, with that you avoid the problems. I recommend to place rvm paths, before system in the PATH variable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47076/discussion-between-sherwyn-goh-and--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to all gems that use the `rdoctask`, probably they require to be updated. You can make shure in it, by entering into [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) project folder, and issuing `grep rdoctask * -r`.

If some of your gems use the `vendor/bundle/` folder, you shall to move it to control by [tag;bundler], because since [ruby-on-rails-4](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4) the folder `vendor/` is deprecated for plugins, and can be used for gems only in case, if you use non open-source or easy-to-install gems, like gems with closed property, or app-specific.

Use [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm)/[rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv) environments to keep gemsets up-to-date, and away of the project. Because it is useful thing to split the keep areas for various [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) apps, so you will avoid encountering the similar problems that you have, to approximate to real work using [heroku](/questions/tagged/heroku) environment, or other servers.

If you issue `bundle show rails` and get the path not leading to `/usr/local` that means you used bundler version of [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) that correctly load your app with `bundle exec`. So, with `bundle exec` you have used non-system ruby, with that you avoid the problems. I recommend to place [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) paths, before system in the **[path](/questions/tagged/path)** variable.

When you use [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm)/[rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv) don use [sudo](/questions/tagged/sudo) operations, if you did it already, setup proper rights to the folder:

```
sudo chown -R sherwyn /Users/sherwyn/.rvm
```

Setup the **.ruby-version**, and **.ruby-gemset** properly for each [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) app you used:

```
echo ruby-2.0.0 > .ruby-version
echo itagora > .ruby-gemset
```

then reenter to the app folder:

```
cd ..
cd app_folder
```

Take a look into [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761318/the-heroku-command-exists-in-these-ruby-versions/20761385#20761385) on notice about [heroku-toolbelt](/questions/tagged/heroku-toolbelt) installation.