# The `heroku' command exists in these Ruby versions:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rbenv, heroku-toolbelt

I'm having major issues with the heroku toolbelt.  I'm using the cedar 14 stack and when I am trying to use a ruby version that isn't `ruby 2.0.0-dev` I get this error.

```
rbenv: heroku: command not found

The `heroku' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.0.0-dev
```

I need heroku to be working with `ruby 1.9.3` and I don't think cedar 14 supports that version of ruby.  Can someone explain first, why I am only allowed to use heroku with `ruby 2.0.0-dev` and also how I can install a older stack that supports `ruby 1.9.3`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that there are two `heroku` executables on your system: one in system paths such as `/usr/local/bin/heroku` (provided by Toolbelt), and one in rbenv's shims because Ruby 2.0.0-dev had "heroku" gem installed.

Because rbenv's shims directory usually have higher precedence, it will block invocation from ever executing the `heroku` executable provided by Toolbelt.

The solution is to uninstall any instance of "heroku" gem and relying solely on Toolbelt for all heroku usage on the command line:

```
for v in `rbenv whence heroku`; do RBENV_VERSION=$v gem uni heroku -ax; done
rbenv rehash
which heroku
```

Comment: The solution didn't work for me, but the explanation on the two hero executables did. And I searched and found the tip -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840977/5965865 -- and followed the instructions to remove rbenv, and heroku now works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1.9.3 on the cedar stack according to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions). The heroku toolbelt is installed as a executable not a ruby gem. How are you trying to execute the command? You should be able to use it from the terminal such as `heroku run rake db:migrate` etc.